# How to enable/install Full Text Search in SQL Server 2014

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2014

There is probably a very simple answer to the question but I have no idea how I'm going to enable Full Text Search in SQL Server 2014.

I've been searching the net for the last couple of hours, some posts about SQL Server 2012 said it's in the features during installation but I went there and I had no options to enabled it.

It is definitely not enabled or installed since I ran

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstall')
```

and got a 0.

To expand on this more, i've created a Full Text Catalog but if I right click on a table the Full-Text Index option is grayed out.

Also if I try run a create Full Text Index command I get the error

> Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know if you have the Express version of SQL Server 2014, but I had the same problem and I solved downloading SQL Server 2014 Express **Advanced Services**, then launching the installer and selecting in the installable features list "Full-text and semantic extractions" under "Instance features", then "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2014".

Reference (for SQL Server 2012, but it worked on my 2014): [msdn Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2014/03/10/adding-sql-server-express-2012-advanced-services-to-existing-development-environment/)